# What does the period stand for in SQL Server Connection strings?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I haven't used SQL Server in a long time and was setting it up.

It appears I can connect to the server using the following 3 strings.

```
(LocalDB)\.
```

this connects to the local database instance of SQL Express.

```
.
```

this connects to my SQL Server instance

```
.\SQLEXPRESS
```

this connects to the SQL Express instance (not the same as the `LocalDB` instance).

I thought that the period after (`LocalDB`) meant to use the default instance. But what does it mean in the other two instances? is period just a symbol for "default", and the default is SQL Server? and then SQL Express is installed under that? or are there two meanings for the period sign.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.` means searching the local machine to find the first instance installed;

`.\SQLEXPRESS` locate the instance named 'SQLEXPRESS' in the local machine.

You can get more details from [SQL Server Connection Strings for ASP.NET Web Applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/jj653752(v=vs.110))